# Ruby ternary operator (or) or operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In Ruby, We often use ternary operator for checking conditions. Similarly we have or operator(||) for using either of the two.

I have scenario where I can use in both ways:
Ternary Operator

```
@question = question.present? ? question : Question.new
```

Or Operator

```
@question = question || Question.new
```

What is the difference between these conditions as both gives the same output? Also which one is better to use in controller method as I am not experienced to decide by my own.

Comment: in Rails you would use [`presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence): `@question = question.presence || Question.new`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference here is that, for example, `[].present?` or `''.present?` both return `false`. So:

```
question = ''
@question = question.present? ? question : Question.new
# => result of Question.new
@question = question || Question.new
# => ''
```

But it shouldn't mean anything in your case if `question` can only hold `nil` or `Question` instance (which is always *present*, assuming it's a regular `ActiveRecord` model). So it's more a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator checks the condition and if it is true returns the first value, else returns the second value. Using it you can specify the condition, upon which to decide what value to return.

The OR operator works the following way - if the first expression is not `nil` or `false`, return it, otherwise return the second expression. Here you are not able to specify the condition, because the check is made directly on the first value you want to return. The OR operator can be represented like:

```
if question
  @question = question
else
  @question = Question.new
end
```

Deciding which one to use depends entirely on the condition you want to apply. In your case you want to assure that the `question` is not `nil`. So the OR operator is fine in this case and is shorter than the ternary operator.
Hope that gives some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

For this case you can use any one of them, both are same.

I would prefer using `@question = question || Question.new` as its easier to read.

However there are many cases where both `||` and ternary operators have different outputs. So you cannot take this for granted.